# flex datagrid scrolls to the top on refresh

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex4, flash-builder

I have a datagrid with a button inside it that is styled based off the value of an item. To get the value to refresh, I call ArrayCollection(sandboxAddAllDg.dataProvider).refresh();, but that has a consequence of the datagrid scrolling to the top.

```
var myidx:int = new int(myDg.selectedIndex);
var myVertPos:int = new int(myDg.verticalScrollPosition);
ArrayCollection(myDg.dataProvider).refresh();
myDg.selectedIndex = myidx;
myDg.verticalScrollPosition = myVertPos;
```

This question was posted on SO a few years ago, but the solutions provided are not satisfactory.  The reason being is that it creates a very visible jump/jerk.  See above code.  Is there a better way to refresh or stop the datagrid from scrolling to the top?

Comment: If you are adding new rows and deleting rows and the arraycollection is binded to the Datagrid, the datagrid should update automatically without refresh().

Comment: I am updating a value, and it doesn't recognize the change until its refreshed.  Is there another way to make it recognize the change without a refresh?